# Finding the position of a word in a file

Tags: shell-script, command-line, grep

I would like to find the position of a given word in a text file.
For instance if I define word variable as abloom word. I would like to find out
I used this command

```
grep -n "$word" mydict.txt
```

but if I define the word variable as "ab". Codes gives the every line which has "ab". For example it gives as well word abloom but I only want ab word's line.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) an example input file ii) the output you want from that example and iii) tell us what operating system you are using. I suspect you are on Linux so you just want `grep -w` but I can't know.

Answer (score 5):

You mean, you want to find line #3 here, but not line #1?

```
abcdefg
foobar
ab cd ef
```

If so, `grep -w` might work for you (GNU manpage):

> `-w`, `--word-regexp`
> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches that form whole words.

What counts as a "word" depends a bit on the locale. In the C locale, "word characters" are letters, digits and the underscore.

So, in these, `ab` is a single whole word:

```
printf 'ab' | grep -w ab
printf 'ab cd' | grep -w ab
printf 'ab-cd' | grep -w ab
printf 'ab, cd' | grep -w ab
```

But not here:

```
printf 'ab_cd' | grep -w ab
printf 'ab1' | grep -w ab
```